# ReferenceError : ShowToast is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Today I started to build my own cordova plugin.
I create a simple toast plugin and try to run it in my Ionic Application.
But I got an error when I try my plugin.

ok let's start with my plugin directory:

this is my CoolPlugin.java in \src\android\

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CoolPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    public static final String TAG = "Cool Plugin";

    /**
    * Constructor.
    */
    public CoolPlugin() {}

    /**
    * Sets the context of the Command. This can then be used to do things like
    * get file paths associated with the Activity.
    *
    * @param cordova The context of the main Activity.
    * @param webView The CordovaWebView Cordova is running in.
    */

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        Log.v(TAG,"Init CoolPlugin");
    }

    public boolean execute(final String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    // Shows a toast
    Log.v(TAG,"CoolPlugin received:"+ action);


    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), action, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    return true;
    }
}
```

this is my CoolPlugin.js in /www

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function CoolPlugin() { 
 console.log("CoolPlugin.js: is created");
}

CoolPlugin.prototype.showToast = function(aString){
    console.log("CoolPlugin.js: showToast");

    exec(function(result){
         /*alert("OK" + reply);*/
      },
    function(result){
        /*alert("Error" + reply);*/
    },"CoolPlugin",aString,[]);
};

var coolPlugin = new CoolPlugin();
module.exports = coolPlugin;
```

That's all my Plugin directory..
let's move to my ionic project.

this is my HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="myText" text="Doh! I'm a Toast!"></input>
     <button id="myButton" title="" onclick="showToast()">Generate Toast!</button>
     <p>
     </p>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function showToast()
         {
            var textValue = document.getElementById("myText").value;
            CoolPlugin.showToast(textValue);
         }

         function onDeviceReady() {
            // console.log("Device ready");
         }
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     </script>
```

I already install the plugin in my project, and also put `<script src="CoolPlugin.js"></script>`in my index.html.
and the last I already put the CoolPlugin.js file in same directory as my index.php.

please check my error.

Comment: index.php? php doesn't work on cordova apps

Comment: edited dude, sorry i mean index.html

Comment: its because its a prototype method you'll have to create an object of `CoolPlugin` to use `showText` in this line `CoolPlugin.showToast(textValue);`

Comment: or simply change `CoolPlugin.prototype.showText = ..` to `CoolPlugin.showText = ..`

Comment: I already try it @Minato but it said CoolPlugin is not a function

Comment: do you have the cordova.js linked in your index.html? you should wait for the deviceready event before calling the CoolPlugin.showToast

Comment: yes @jcesarmobile, I already included cordova.js in my index.html, but the error still there

Comment: try putting `var CoolPlugin = cordova.require("CoolPlugin.js");` in the start of your script tag.